# Linux application like Mac OSX Preview

Tags: linux

Is there any equivalent linux application to Preview on Mac OSX?

By this I mean that it lets you view, but not necessarily edit many different file types from things such as documents to photos.

Comment: Are you thinking of [Quick Look](http://support.apple.com/kb/ph6370) instead? Just curious.

Comment: Nope, definitely preview.

Comment: Does it have to be a single application, or can it be a way to launch a format-specific application? Is the lack of editing features important? You need to tell us more precisely what you want, and also explain why you want it — tell us your story. See our [tips on writing good questions](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: I mean one application that can open and view lots of different types of files, as I often need to quickly look at lots of different file types. It doesn't need to be able to edit them, but this functionality would not be a problem. By different types of files, I mean PDFs, as many different types of picture as possible, but also microsoft office formats.

Answer (score 1):

- [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/): You can view

  - All Text-Based formats, including: HTML, CSS, XML, Markdown, Text files, JavaScript
  - Some image formats: JPG, gif, png
  - Documents: PDF
  - Videos: AVI
  - Container formats: Flash
  - and much more, when you have the necessary plugins / extensions / addons
- [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/): All sorts of "image-like" documents. This includes PDF and ps files.
- [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/): All types of text-based documents